# ImageIO.read(inputStream) returns invalid icc profile data error

Tags: java, javax.imageio

In my project, I'm reading a picture like this:

```
BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(inputStream);
```

But from time to time, this method throwing exception **Invalid icc profile data error**.
When I checked the imported image, I found out that image bytes field contains text **ICC_PROFILE**
[Here is example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7wiO.png). But the funny thing is that when I change the bytes to 0000 in the position where this text is, everything works.

And [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwdUL.jpg) is the picture where the exception occures. For testing.

Please help with the solution.

Comment: It works without problems for me. What JDK are you using?

Comment: I'm using JDK8.

Comment: But now I found out that my development environment (Oracle jDeveloper) using JDK5.

Comment: JDK5?! Oh dear. I've tested down to JDK 8 and it all works. Just for your information: I've started with JDK 17.

Comment: And the last info: the java server use JDK4. This is really problem.

Comment: I know that this is a problem. The application I manage is very old. I tried to change java to 8 in the application but the application returned 50 errors when compiling. And there are several such applications in our company. So this problem is unsolvable.

Comment: While it it is a completely different problem, you really should upgrade those applications to use a new version of Java. Keep in mind that the old version don't get upgrades and may present serious security issues. Language-wise, there's not much changes from Java 5 to 8, so the compilation errors should be fixable in hours rather than days (unless you do very nasty things in your existing code).

Answer (score 0):

What you see in your hex editor, is the JPEG APP2 segment, containing an embedded ICC color profile. This profile says something about how the colors in the image are to be interpreted.

As this is a normal (YCC encoded) RGB image, you can skip this segment, and the image will still look "okay", but the colors may be a little off. When you change the "identifier" of the APP2 segment from exactly `"ICC_PROFILE"` (and a 0-terminator) in the editor, you make this a different segment and the decoder will ignore (skip) it when reading.

Regarding the exception, it is possible that the software that wrote the JPEG (or the ICC profile embedded in it) wrote an incorrect ICC profile. But this doesn't seem to be the case after looking at the file. The other likely option is that this particular ICC profile is not supported by the Java runtime environment you are running on. If you are running on Java 5 (!) I suggest you just upgrade right away, as this version was end-of-life'd years ago. If you are on Java 8, there might be reasons for that, but I still suggest upgrading to Java 11 or 17, if you can.

If you still experience problems reading JPEGs due to ICC profile issues, you could try using my [TwelveMonkeys ImageIO JPEG plugin](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys), which does some tricks to hot-fix bad ICC profiles, or just ignore them (with a warning) if they can't be fixed. It does require Java 8 though...

Comment: The problem is Java. JDE using jdk5 and the server using jdk4. And is not possible change it to higher version unfortunately :(